# How to merge two or more rows where some columns have same values and some have different values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample Data output after joining 2 different tables on ProductNumber

| ProductNumber | QuantityOnHand | VendorID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 401 |
| 1 | 5 | 501 |

I want to write a query that would return this output

| ProductNumber | QuantityOnHand | VendorID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 401 & 501 |

I'm still pretty new to SQL. Stuck on a homework problem here. I don't really know which aggregated function to use to make it work. Sum() but I don't want to add the vendorIDs. Concat() but they're from the same column name.

Comment: is it mysql or MS-SQLSERVER?

Comment: ...or some other database?

Comment: Please specify the DBMS. It is not part of standard SQL definition. Each DBMS has its own implementation.

Comment: I think it's MS-SQLServer.

Comment: Looks like you need to sum the quanity and string_agg the Id. You don't provide neither table definitions, query or sample data so not really possible to say anything further.

Answer (score 1):

If it is SQL Server, then you need `STRING_AGG` function for cancatenating the same column in different rows and `SUM` for totalling:

```
SELECT ProductNumber, 
    SUM(QuantityOnHand),
    STRING_AGG(VendorID, ' & ')
FROM Product
GROUP BY ProductNumber
```

I assumed the table name is `Product`, as you did not provide one. You can update it to your actual table name.